# Why is my DataPager causing multiple MouseButtonUp events to be throw?

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a DataGrid and a DataPager bound to a DomainDataSource. That part works fine. The problem is, I have a function to handle double clicking on a DataGridRow

```
    private void dataGrid_list_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Row.AddHandler(Control.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_MouseLeftButtonDown), true);
    }
```

The actual logic of Row_MouseLeftButtonDown isn't important. It works fine, except for once I've clicked to another page using the DataPager. Now I'm showing that I've got two Mouse Clicks firing at the same time (which is triggering my double click when it shouldn't). If I click through four pages, I register FIVE clicks when I click on a row (one for the row click, and I guess one for each time I clicked to change pages with the DataPager)

Any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it? I tried putting a random button on the page that doesn't do anything, and clicking that doesn't cause this problem, so it doesn't seem to be just any click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event is being registered each time `dataGrid_list_LoadingRow` is called which must be happening whenever you click to another page.

```
private void dataGrid_list_LoadingRow(object sender, DataGridRowEventArgs e)
{
    e.Row.RemoveHandler(Control.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, Row_MouseLeftButtonDown);
    e.Row.AddHandler(Control.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, Row_MouseLeftButtonDown, true);
}
```

On the first time this is hit, `RemoveHandler` will not cause any problems as it will simply have no effect, according to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.removehandler%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). But on the second time this function is hit, it will remove the initially registered handler and simply add it again. This way, you won't just keep building up the list of registered handlers.

Also, `new MouseButtonEventHandler(Row_MouseLeftButtonDown)` is not necessary, you can just use `Row_MouseLeftButtonDown` (see [Add/Remove handler to textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657503/add-remove-handler-to-textbox)).

Comment: Ah hah! That was it! I never would have thought that the handler was being added over and over. I was so stumped by this, thank you!