# Assigning event GotFocus to all TextBoxes in WPF-Aplication

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, error-handling, controls

I wanted to add GotFocus-Event to every Textbox in my WPF-Aplication, because its for Touch Devices and everytime a TextBox is in use the OSK should open. I got Problems with procedure adding the Event to my TextBoxes. The Aplication is already build for pc (I'm in an interhsip and my goal is it to bring this Apl. to Windows 8 Touch Devices).This is the link, where I got my Inspiration from: [Add/Remove handler to textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8657503/add-remove-handler-to-textbox)

and here is my Solution:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control tb in this.Controls)
    {
        if (tb is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)tb;
            tb1.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
        }
    }
}

private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    KeyBoardManager.LaunchOnScreenKeyboard();
}
```

when I want to run this Code I have the following Error:

> Error 1   'OSK_Test.MainWindow' does not contain a definition for
>   'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first
>   argument of type 'OSK_Test.MainWindow' could be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What have I got to do, that it works? And of course it's the same with LostFocus!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem as I see it is that you are using an answer meant for a `Winforms application` with a `Wpf application`, in the Winforms your controls can be added to the main form, therefore `this.Controls` works, in Wpf your `MainWindow` has a `Content` Property which can contain only one item, usually a `Grid`, `Canvas` or `Panel` of some kind. This object is where your `TextBox's` are located.

**Note:** this will work only if your TextBox's are children of the MainWindows LayoutControl and not Embedded any deeper if it is embedded deeper you will need to name the Panel that they are contained in and iterate through that, **also I am not suggesting that this is the proper way to approach your problem, just trying to point out what your problem is**:

```
private void Grid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control tb in ((Panel)this.Content).Children)
    {
        if (tb is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)tb;
            tb1.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
            tb1.LostFocus += tb1_LostFocus;
        }

    }

}
```

---

Based on OP's comment:

You will need to give your StackPpanel a name or use an existing one if one exists. i.e.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="MyStackPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
    <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
    <TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Usuage would be something like this:

```
 public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    foreach (Control tb in MyStackPanel.Children)
    {
        if (tb is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox tb1 = (TextBox)tb;
            tb1.GotFocus += TextBox_GotFocus;
            tb1.LostFocus += tb1_LostFocus;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay. I wasn't sure how different WinForms is from WPF. I thought I give it a try. And thanks for the answer. But I it didn't worked out (I'm in an intership and very new at wpf :D). Just for your information: The textboxes are in a stackpanel so this should work because its a panel? And you said you couldn't see my problem: I have a nearly ready wpf apl. (for pc) and i should change it for Tablets. So I want, when you use a Textbox, that the OnScreenKeyBoard is opened. But once again thanks for your help!!!

Comment: No what I said was "Your problem as I see it is ..." As far as using a stackpanel you will have to give it a name, then iterate through its Children collection. I will try to put a small example up.

Comment: Thank you a loooooooooot! Now I understand it. Works out fine!

Answer (score 9):

You can do better, add below code to app.xaml.cs:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        EventManager.RegisterClassHandler(typeof(TextBox),
            TextBox.GotKeyboardFocusEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(TextBox_GotFocus));

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can easily achieved it using user control with textbox inheritance .

```
 public UserTextbox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.GotFocus += (sender, args) => 
            {
                //your code here

            };
        }
```

This user control you can use every where in you project you want.

Comment: At first, thank you for your answer, but the problem is, that the wpf is already build by someone else and it is actually for pc and should change for Tablets (I'm am in an intership ). So I didn't want to change every textbox. But once again thank you for your answer and I learned something new!!!

Answer (score 0):

Add a GotFocus handler to your root element in your window.
Assuming your root element is a Grid, it would be

```
    <Grid name="root" GotFocus="root_GotFocus">
```

In your code

```
    private void root_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox tb = e.OriginalSource as TextBox;
        if(tb != null)
        {
             //do your thing
             KeyBoardManager.LaunchOnScreenKeyboard();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't get it to work (but I think this is my fault :D). Is the root element the element the textboxes are in in (this is stackpanel) or the first element at all, where everything is in (this is a grid in my case). Once again thanks for your help!

Comment: You should check out routed events http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806(v=vs.110).aspx  GotFocus is a bubbling event that's why you can handle it on the parent container.  I would also place the handler in the stackpanel.  If it still doesn't work, you probably have some other control that's handling the event.  Use Snoop to see what's happening to the events.  http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/

Comment: Okay. I will have a look! Once again thank you, for your answer!